# How do I show admin-only links in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-interface

Sorry if this is a rookie question but here it goes:

I want the Admin (when logging into the site) to view a link that non-admins can't view when they log in. I'm not even sure how to get started. I know I have to add two separate routes to the routes.js file. But not really sure how to display that in the UI or if I'm even correct.

This repo seems somewhat relatable to my problem. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#get-started

Thanks

Comment: All you do is create some kind of authentication at which point (in response to the authentication) you send the data required to create the new link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the best way (using angular as you are) to create admin pages is to restrict them on your API within express or node.

**Luckily there is a package for this**! [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) a node module which can not only do regular logins but also google, facebook and many others.

I would take a look at there middleware examples then in your route you can do something as simple as this:

```
app.get('/admin', isAdmin ,function(req,res){
    res.send('Secret Admin Things')
});
```

where `isadmin` will handle checking if they are an admin all in one swoop! [Amazing tutorial for this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local).

Comment: Awesome! so one more question, since I'm creating a separate admin route, will that mean a new view will have to be created apart from the non-admin user log in? I shouldn't have to right?

Comment: No a new view wouldn't have to be needed you can tell the router to load the view with the different data, and use ng-show="admin" to show admin only things or ng-hide="admin" to show only user only things. In this case you have to define in angular $scope if admin is true or false.

Answer (score 2):

I worked on a project which did not make use of passport and this is what they did

In the back end

```
res.locals = {
    auth: req.session.auth,
  }

  res.render('index');
```

Then in the front end

HTML:

```
 <span id="admin"> </span>
```

JavaScript:

```
 if('{{auth}}' == admin){
    menu = "<a href='/admin/users'> Admin: Users </a>"
    $('#admin').append(menu)
 }
```

Then to make sure someone could not look at the code to find the link and go to it you of course secure the back end

```
if (req.session.auth !== 'admin') { //
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

The other answers are great if your using and know angular and passport. However, not everyone uses the same libraries so if your just using express and JQuery this option will work to get you started. There is much more to the code as far as security checks etc you would want to do but this is the basic way

Comment: If you're using templates in express, you should probably use that instead of relying on jQuery to append it on the client?